# Linked List and BST Trees find the lowest

Tags: java

I am studying for my cs midterm exam for next week. We received a sample midterm exam and I want to know if I am doing this correctly.

1. Write a method public T lowest() that returns the largest element in the class.

   ```
   public class List<T extends Comparable<T>>
   { 
        private Node<T> head;
        // some methods here
        private class Node<T>
        {
            T data;
            Node<T> next;
        }
   }
   ```

   Here is my answer:

   ```
   public T lowest()
   {
      if(head == null)
          return null; 

   Node<T> pointer = head;
   T min = pointer.data;

   while(pointer != null)
   {
       if(pointer.data.compareTo(min) < 0) // 
       {
           min = pointer.data;
           pointer = pointer.next;
       }
   }
   return min;
   ```

   }
2. Write a method public T lowest() that returns the lowest value stored int the tree.

   ```
    public class BST<T extends Comparable<T>>
    {
       private Node<T> root;
       // some methods here
       private class Node<T>
       {
            T data;
            Node<T> left, right;
       }
   }
   ```

Here is my answer:

```
public T lowest()
{
    Node current = root;
    while(current.left != null)
    {
        current = current.left;
    }
    return current.data;
}
```

Comment: For Q2, do you want to find the lowest node value in the tree or the lowest leaf in the tree? In any case, you are doing it wrong. Your code will return the data value of leftmost leaf in the tree.

Comment: @JayeshDoolani I thought the leftmost leaf always has the lowest value so that is why i returned that value

Comment: ah, you're right. I thought it's a general Binary tree and not a BST. In that case you'r code will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your code has a bug in while loop where it will go in an infinite loop. You are only advancing the pointer ahead if it finds a node having value less than current minimum. You have to keep advancing the pointer no matter what, and update the min variable when your condition is met. The wile loop should be like this:

   `while(pointer != null) {
       if(pointer.data.compareTo(min) < 0) {
           min = pointer.data;
       }
       pointer = pointer.next;
   }`

Comment: Thank You I didn't catch thatt